# Compactness of the unit ball in the space of Radon measures w.r.t. the Kantorovich-Rubinstein norm

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, measure-theory, metric-spaces, optimal-transportation, lipschitz-spaces

*This question was posted previously but has not attracted any responses so I am repharising it in a slightly different language hoping to reach a wider community*

Let $(X,d)$ be a pointed metric space with base point $x_0$. Denote by $Lip_0(X)$ the set of all Lipschitz functions on $X$ vanishing at $x_0$. The norm in $Lip_0$ is defined as $\|f\|_{Lip_0} := Lip(f)$, where $Lip(f)$ denotes the Lipschitz constant.

Denote by $\mathcal M_0^1(X)$ the space of balanced Radon measures on $X$ with a finite first moment, i.e. such that $\mu(X)=0$ and
$$
\int_X d(x,x_0) d|\mu|(x) < +\infty.
$$
The total variation norm on $\mathcal M_0^1(X)$ is defined by $\|\mu\|_{\mathcal M} := |\mu|(X)$.

Another norm on $\mathcal M_0^1(X)$ can be defined using pairings with functions from $Lip_0(X)$
$$
\|\mu\|_{KR} := \sup\left\{ \int f \, d\mu \colon \|f\|_{Lip_0} \leq 1  \right\},
$$
where KR stands for Kantorovich-Rubinstein because of a connection to optimal transport.

If $X$ is compact then the closed unit ball $\{\mu \in \mathcal M_0(X) \colon \|\mu\|_{\mathcal  M} \leq 1\}$  is compact w.r.t. the Kantorovich-Rubinstein norm, see Theorem VIII.4.3 in [Kantorovich and Akilov. Functional Analysis](https://shop.elsevier.com/books/functional-analysis/kantorovich/978-0-08-023036-8).

Does a similar result hold in more general cases? It is likely to require a uniform bound on the first moments, so more presicely:

**Question**. Let
$$
M := \left\{\mu \in \mathcal M_0^1(X) \colon \|\mu\|_{\mathcal  M} \leq 1, \, \int_X d(x,x_0) d|\mu|(x) \leq 1 \right\}.
$$
Is $M$ compact w.r.t. the Kantorovich-Rubinstein norm?

I am interested in the following three scenarios:

(i) $X$ is locally compact;
(ii) $X$ is the unit ball in a Banach space;
(iii) $X$ is a Banach space.

Any help will be much appreciated.